# boost::ptr_vector sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, ptr-vector

i have a boost::ptr_vector that i want to keep maintained in sorted order.

i am creating a bunch of Customer objects containing several simple strings and values, which are then stored in a boost::ptr_vector, and they need to be ordered by one of the strings.

i have looked around but cant seem to find much information about the boost::ptr_vector member functions though, it appears that there is one called sort() which i think is relevant to what i am trying to do, however there is not much information on usage of this function.

is there an "insert in order" type function available to boost::ptr_vector? or do i need to load everything into the vector and then sort afterwards?

any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking too much of your `ptr_vector`. A `ptr_vector` is just a wrapper to `std::vector`. Likewise, there exist other wrappers to stdlib data structures.

A data structure that is always sorted (by performing sorted inserts) is the `std::set`. To use that functionality, you can use a `boost::ptr_set`. See here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_set.html

Comment: thanks for that, but unfortunately this is for a uni assignment and it is explicitly stated that we need to use a boost::ptr_vector for this part of the assignment.. the reason for this is we are comparing the efficiency of different datastructures, and boost::ptr_vector is one of them..

Comment: Sounds very much like you will have to implement a bad solution exactly to show and learn that ptr_vector is not as efficient for your task as ptr_set and others... So to answer the question that way: No, it is not available with ptr_vector. The reason being it would be an inefficient use of the data structure. ;-) You can always write your own insertion method that querys the ptr_vector and uses insert(). It will be slower.